# Problem accessing api on port 4001 on certain networks

Tags: networking, axios

I have a website that uses axios to do https api calls to a backend service which is separated from website.
The api endpoint is located on a subdomain 'api.website.com' but due to what i think is unrelated problems with the loadbalancer i had to put it on port 4001. I've also set up CORS responses.

Its been working well for most of my users but a few get a very unclear error where their requests to the api either time out or get a obscure 'Network Error' error message. After talking with two of them it seems that the problem was only present on their office network, but when they switched to their mobile or home network it was fixed.

So what I wan't to know is if it's common practice in corporate or office environments to block outgoing requests to ports other than the common 443 and 80, or could my problem be elsewhere such as having the api on a subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of firewalls / public wifi setups, ... are blocking everything but TCP 80 an 443. and sometimes the even inspect if TCP80 definitely is HTTP traffic, and 443 is valid ssl.

and outbound DNS probably also blocked, if those other filters are in use.

You are best of with a reverse proxy (or load balancer). which redirects a part of your url of another domain to your internal port 4001

Comment: Yeah, got the loadbalancer setup properly using port 443 and redirected all traffic to url /api to the proper port. Pretty much instantly observed an sharp decline in network errors being reported by sentry.